# how to get Confirmation and form submit or Abort in code behind.. here i used Code below

Tags: asp.net

if (chk > 0)
 {
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", Confirm('Want to Save?');", true);

**// I want Section Below this Line Restricted by Confirmation Ok or Cancel..**

string qry = "insert into userip values('" + TextBox2.Text + "'," + ddluid.Text + ")";
SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand(qry, con); con.Open(); insert.ExecuteNonQuery(); con.Close(); TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex = 1;
 }

//
//If Yes/OK clicked Segment run Else... Return to Form back.

Answer (score 0):

look at here http://forums.asp.net/t/963412.aspx asp:Button Validation with OnClientClick